# Page Change Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

#### My Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sx9Rt/2/

#### My problem

I have a page, called page1. After I navigate to page2, I want to CHANGE page1 so that next time it is visited, it will look in a certain way (for example, background-color blue). I want to make this change only AFTER the end of the transition to page2.

I was trying to correctly use the `pagecontainerchange` event in JQM 1.4 and it wouldn't work for me. I don't want to use the `pagechange` event because it has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/sx9Rt/12/)**

The pagecontainershow event of the pagecontainer widget runs after the animation to the new page is complete. In the event you can check the toPage or prevPage properties to figure out where you came from and where you are going.

```
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
    var prevPageID =  ui.prevPage.prop("id");
    if (prevPageID == "page1"){
          toDoAfterTransition();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/sx9Rt/13/

Use this:

```
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).on( "pagecontainerhide", function( event, ui ) {
    $("#page1").css('background', 'blue');
});
```

API doc: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascripts `setInterval` function to check the visibility of the page.

```
var prevPage;

$(document).on('click', 'a[data-role="button"]', function(){
    prevPage = $(this).parents('[data-role="page"]');

    var checkVisibility = setInterval(function() {
        if(!$(prevPage).is(':visible')) {
            $(prevPage).css('background', 'blue');
            clearInterval(checkVisibility);
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sx9Rt/11/